# rewriting urls with Apache mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have an application that is shared by two domains;
domain1.com and domain2.com both have in their virtual directories:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^/application(.*)$ c:/server/web/application/www/$1
```

so that domain1.com/application and domain2.com/application both point to it, and I don't have to physically put the application in a folder under each domain.

now, I want to start having deeper urls look 'nicer':

```
domain1.com/application/account/0322734174/notes/desc
```

instead of:

```
domain1.com/application/account/index.php?number=0322734174&view=notes&sort=desc
```

but I m having trouble getting it to work with anything, and everything that I try does nothing. I think it's a rule conflict ?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: everything, stuff like ^(.*)$ /index.php?number=$1 and then echo $_GET['number'] placed in the account folder and i try account/0322734174 and page not found. even tried .htaccess

Comment: Add your attempted rules to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
RewriteLog
RewriteLogLevel 4
```

is your friend (plus lots of trial and error and time)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/application/(.*)$ c:/server/web/application/www/$1
RewriteRule ^c:/server/web/application/www/account/([^/\.]+)/?$ c:/server/web/application/www/account/index.php?action=$1
```

works. had to use absolute path after first rule

thanks for your time